# How do I interpolate between bins on an FFT in python?

Tags: python-2.7, fft, interpolation

I have four frequency peaks, which I have after applying FFT. Now I want to know precise values of these frequency peaks. there are different interpolation methods.
How can I use this method of interpolation for four frequency peaks by using python

```
k=index of the max (possibly local) magnitude of an DFT
X[i]=bin "i" of an DFT 
|X[i]|=magnitude of DFT at bin "i“
k'=the interpolated bin location

Quadradic Method
y1=|X[k - 1]|
y2=|X[k]|
y3=|X[k + 1]|
d=(y3 - y1) / (2 * (2 * y2 - y1 - y3))
k'=k + d

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/how-do-i-interpolate-between-bins-on-an-fft-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very precise estimate, then use Sinc interpolation instead of parabolic, and perhaps successive approximation to locate the extrema.